# emphasize clickable areas in a data visualization

Tags: info-visualisation, charts, affordance

I want to show a stacked bar chart (single bar) that only one part of it (the dark green one that has 15%) is clickable, when clicked this section will drill down. 
see examples below:

stacked bar option:
[image: Before drill down]

[image: After drill down]

any suggestions?

Comment: Why only one section? Can you provide some more context of the problem you’re trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Try placing emphasis on the legend, so it's persistent in size and prominence regardless of the % of the dataset.

You could try to suggest the drilldown in the data, but you'll run into problems where you have a small % of the whole, but still is important to inspect: this means there's less pixel area to both suggest interactivity, and for the user to actually select and drilldown on the data.

Use the legend; it's persistent, and you can try using borders, text or a combo of both.

[image]

Comment: Makes good sense!

Comment: Good Idea!
let me try that :)